# Where to get Android 1.0.0 API 2 SDK Platform

Tags: android

I just checked out the files in the repository for Cool Reader.
I compiled it againt API7 but it's not working like the version I downloaded. It's not showing the icons and it doesn't open files.

In in it's README file it says:

> If you are a developer, please use the Eclipse Ganymede 3.4 version, SDK for RC2, ADT 0.8, JDK 1.6 Version
>   And Eclipse working directory encoding for UTF-8.

I don't know what is SDK for RC2.
and this is part of the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="cn.itcreator.android.reader" android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="2"></uses-sdk>
```

I tried to download Android 1.0.0 API 2 but I couldn't find it. In the SDK manager, the minimum version available is 3.

What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, that version of the SDK is no longer available. It is a shame that it isn't there, but you are better served popping open the Cool Reader source and figuring out where it went wrong (messy as that may be).

HOWEVER: see http://developer.android.com/sdk/older_releases.html. Might have what you want.